# Dart: hard to understand anonymous functions

Tags: dart

I am a very newbie in Dart and have big trouble to understand the "shortcut" of Dart code.
One of them is the "(...) {...}".
Could you take a look at the attached screenshot and help me to understand what are the "(..)" in blue and red rectangles? 
Thank you!

```dart
child: Switch(
  value: isSwitched,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      isSwitched = value;
      print(isSwitched);
    });
  },
  activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  activeColor: Colors.green,
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I understood about those 2 onChanged and setState. Just do not understand the parentheses, I mean the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions are called anonymous functions.

The `onChange` function took a function as an argument. And run that function with an argument it already has.

```dart
void fn(value) {
  // setState code
}
// which you can use as
onChanged: fn,
```

But declaring a new function just to use at that one place can be tiresome and inefficient. That's why anonymous functions are useful. So you can write the previous code with anonymous functions as

```dart
onChanged: () { // the same as function fn but with no name or declaration
  // setState code
}
```

The same goes for `setState` function. But it takes a function with no arguments.

Comment: @Espanola You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: An anonymous function is a function without a name, but not without a declaration. The difference is precisely the fact that the declaration does not contain a name. How can it be declared without a declaration?

Comment: @mezoni Yeah, you're right. The term wasn't sufficient, I wanted to say name-specified-declaration that can be consumed.